# MySQL backup and restore from command line

Tags: backup, mysql, restore

I am using Command line to backup and restore MYSQL Database.
Let use I m having a Database Data1 having Views and Procedures in it.
When in `Cmd line`, I use `mysqldump` i.e

```
..>bin> mysqldump -u root -proot Data1 > Datafile.mysql
```

When I use above Cmd, It creates a Backup file on bin Folder of Mysql with `Dtafile.mysql`
Name.

but the thing is it creates Back Up of Only Tables, Not Procedures.

And when I m restoring it in a Blank Database "Data2"

```
..bin> mysql - u root -proot Data2 < Dataafile.mysql
```

What it does is, It creates all the Tables and Convert Views into Tables and No Procedures has been restored.

Means I am not able to Restore my full database backup with All tables, views and Procedures.

Can any of you guys help it..
I would be extremely Thankfull.

Answer (score 12):

Include the "--routines" parameter for mysqldump and it will dump the procedures.

EDIT #1 :
Your mysqldump command should now look like,

```
mysqldump -u root -proot --routines Data1 > Datafile.mysql
```

EDIT #2: 
You need to add the --add-drop-table switch as well if you want to preserve your Views. The reason is Views are created in two steps (first as dummy tables, then as real views). Also please take a note that Tables and Views share the same name space, so don't get misled by the output given by "Show Tables" command in the mysqlclient. Use "Show Create View vw_test" instead if that command shows you the create view query then bingo, also to make sure that the views have been restored correctly insert some data into the relevant tables in your other database and then run a select query on the view, if the data ties up than you hit a bulls eye, pat yourself on the back :) else you can always return to this wonderful community at Stackoverflow.

So (to maintain views) your mysqldump command should now look like this

```
mysqldump -u root -proot --routines --add-drop-table Data1 > Datafile.mysql
```

HTH

Comment: Hey how do I include --routines while taking dump?? CAn you plz explain a bit

Comment: Hi, I have edited my answer above to show the command to use.

Comment: Hi Thanks..
It Works.. One More Problem, I am facing Is that in "Data1" I am having Views that refers other databases. when I am restoring it, It convert all Views into tables. i.e I m having View vw_test in Data1 but when I restore it, It becomes a table with Name vw_test.

What would be the problem. 
Help me.

Thanks a Lot.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply, but .. It doesn't work.
Still the script convert Views(Having Reference to other database) into Tables.

Comment: Show Create Table shows the Table structure of vw_test.
Create Table vw_test(id int...) in this manner.

Comment: You probably didn't read my comment properly, I asked you to run "Show Create View vw_test" not "Show Create Table". Also what version of mysql are you running, everything at my end is running fine. Did you insert some data in the other database and then run a select query on your view what was the result?

Comment: Hi Anand, I am trying with writing "Show create view" but it is showing, vw_test is not a view.

Comment: Is mysqldump giving you any errors when restoring the database. Also please paste the "Create View" query that you are running to create the view in the database. Also have you considered using MySQL Administrator GUI for back/restore operations.

Comment: Hey Anand.. I am really thankful for your precious time, Can I have your Id Plz, I can Attach a file and send to ur ID.

Comment: "Create Database Test"
---------------------
"Create Database Test1"
Use Test1
Create Table Test1(id int, fname varchar(20))
-------------------
Create Database Test2
Create Table Test2(id int, lname varchar(20))

delimiter $$
create view vw_Test2
as
select * from Test2
$$
delimiter ;

delimiter $$
Create View vw_Test1
as
select * from Test1.Test1
$$
delimiter ;
----------------------------

For Backup: 
>mysqldump -u root -proot --routines --add-drop-tables Test2>test.mysql
----------------
For Restore
 >mysql -u roout -proot test<test.mysql
----------------

Comment: I guess you are missing a "Use Database Test2" somewhere in your script pasted above, using the script given above all the tables and views get created in Database Test1, your Database Test2 is blank...so on restoring nothing gets restored as Test2 is blank. 

If you still have problems paste your email id and I will reply you on that email id. Regards, Anand

Comment: Hi Anand, I have Drpo you a mail, with Proper Explanation.

Answer (score -1):

there is three best ways to backup database use command line,phpmyadmin or mysql administrator
mysql database backup and restore in easy way, use mysql database backup

[mysql administrator](http://gleegrid.com/blog/mysql-database-backup/)

[phpmyadmin](http://gleegrid.com/blog/mysql-database-backup-using-phpmyadmin/)