# How to take Mysql Backup without using script?

Tags: mysql, backup

Is it possible to take daily backup (Only the records per day) for particular table in DB.Once the backup is done need to delete those records from table.

Is this scenario will work without using scripting language like php,perl...?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/823841/mysql-backup-and-restore-from-command-line It shows you how to backup the database and restore it via the command line. You can create a batch file and then schedule the batch to be run at certain times.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to use script

1) select records you need

2) put them in some form of dump

3) run delete from table with parameters you need

other constructions (triggers with stored procedures or else), IMHO, will shoot you in leg eventually

Comment: The above “script” can be a *shell* script (batch file on Windows), which might be considered easier than the PHP or Perl the OP worried about.

Answer (score 0):

```
 mysqldump -u root -p db_name > db_backup.sql
```

using above command we can back up database and if you want to take the back up of a seleted table you can use : `mysqldump -c -u -p db_name table_name > table_backup.sql`
And to drop the db use `drop database db-name` and to drop a specific table use `drop table table-name`